# Is there a list of the common show routines in Vxworks?

Tags: vxworks

In the vxWorks shell, there are a number of routines you can use to display information about the system.

These routines are usually referred to as **show** routines because they tend to have the form of "xxxShow".

Is there a list of these routines available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I work with VxWorks 5.5 and use the symbol lookup function "lkup" to find functions and/or variables that I may be interested in.

Execute the following command where ">" is the VxWorks shell prompt.

```
> lkup "Show"
```

This will output a list of symbols that include the "Show" in their name, including all of the "Show" functions. The lkup command is interactive and will prompt you if there is more than one console screen worth of symbols before continuing.

Comment: pardon, in my vxworks I can't access to `inetstatShow` function... [why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094993/c-interp-unknown-symbol-name-inetstatshow)

Answer (score 4):

There is no comprehensive list of all the show routines available.  This will depend on your kernel configuration and what components are included.

Here are a few show routines that I have found useful in the past.

adrSpaceShow(details 0, 1) - Show details of the Address Space, including physical address, User Region address and kernel virtual mapping.

envShow(taskId) -  Show environment for a given task

iosDevShow - Show loaded I/O Devices

iosDrvShow - Show I/O Device Driver Function Table

iosFdShow - show open File Descriptors

memShow - show memory usage statistics

moduleShow - show downloaded modules

objShowAll - show the list of all the objects in the system (semaphores, tasks, msgQs, etc...)

objShow (objectId) - show detailed information about an object

Comment: pardon, in my vxworks I can't access to `inetstatShow` function... [why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094993/c-interp-unknown-symbol-name-inetstatshow)