# C interp: unknown symbol name 'inetstatShow'

Tags: command, embedded, vxworks, netstat

I have some `Vxworks` embedded os and I want to check the `netstat`.

This is what I tried:

```
-> inetstatShow
```

And the output is:

```
C interp: unknown symbol name 'inetstatShow'.
```

How can I have `netstat` command in this?

Answer (score 2):

[`inetstatShow`](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/netShow.html#inetstatShow) is provided by [netShow](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/netShow.html) library - you need to be sure that your OS configuration includes netShow, or you can dynamically load it using [`ld`](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/usrLib.html#ld).

The `lkup` function can be used to list symbols that are available to the shell.  Try `lkup "Show"` to list all symbols that include the sub-string "Show" for example.

Comment: Thank you... Can I load the module from remote host? how?

Comment: @MortezaLSC : It is a long time since I have used VxWorks. `ld` is odd in that it takes input from stdin, so you must use redirection to use a file.  If you can access the remote object file from your VxWorks target, then you can load it. http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/usrLib.html#ld

Comment: So you mean I should compile `netstat` in my vxworks? I only have remote access to my vxworks machine and my os on my pc is linux. Firstly I should login to vxworks then load compiled netstat code? :(

Comment: If you want netShow permanently in your OS, then you should configure VxWorks accordingly.  If it is just a development requirement, load it from your development host as necessary.

Comment: +1 ... Thank you I am closing to the answer. is it possible for me to compile c program on my ubuntu then load `compiled.o` file to the remote vxworks? how?

Answer (score 1):

VxWorks supports `netstat` command.

```
-> netstat "-n -a" /* state of sockets */
-> netstat "-n -r" /* routing table */
```

Comment: As @Clifford said, this works only if the netShow lib is included in the vxworks kernel and if INCLUDE_NETSTAT is also enabled in the kernel config.